# Defining zeropage address labels in xa assembler?

Tags: assembly, 6502

I am trying to use the [xa](https://www.floodgap.com/retrotech/xa/) assembler to write some 6502 code. According to [the documentation](https://www.floodgap.com/retrotech/xa/xa.1.html), I can define a zeropage segment using the `.zero` pseudo-op. I was hoping to do something like this:

```
.zero

tmp1: .byt 0
tmp2: .byt 0

.text

      lda $12
      sta tmp1
      lda $34
      sta tmp2
```

I am hoping for this output:

```
a512 8500 a534 8501
```

But trying to assemble the above fails with:

```
foo.s:line 1: 1000:Illegal segment error
```

According to the docs, "These pseudo-ops are valid in relative and absolute modes". Just for kicks, I tried enabling relocatable mode (`xa -R ...`), which compiles the code without error, but now I have an `o65` format file instead of raw assembly output (and linking that with `ldo65` produces an `o65` binary).

Is it possible to use segment pseudo-ops in xa while still producing raw assembly output?

---

@Raffzahn asked for complete command lines. Assuming the code is in file `xatest.s`, this fails:

```
xa xatest.s
```

This fails:

```
xa -bz 0 -bt 512 xatest.s
```

This completes without error, but doesn't produce useful output:

```
xa -R xatest.s
```

Comment: Not sure, but IIRC `.text` is only allowed in relocatable format. Maybe the issue is just reported with a wrong line number? Also, in non relocatable mode the Assembler needs a well a hint were to start. Next, when using relocatable format, the linker needs to be given addresses for each segment. This can be done with the assembler as well (`-b*`), so maybe theres somethign to try (P.S.: addin the whole command line with all options used may be a good idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code achieves the output you want:

```
    tmp1=$00
    tmp2=$01

* = $100
    lda $12
    sta tmp1
    lda $34
    sta tmp2
```

I don't think the segment identifiers are really intended to be used in raw output. They're for relocatable object files, as the documentation tries to allude to:

> The following pseudo-ops apply primarily to relocatable .o65 objects.
> A full discussion of the relocatable format is beyond the scope of this
> manpage, as it is currently a              format in flux.
> Documentation on the proposed v1.2 format is in doc/fileformat.txt
> within the xa installation directory.

Comment: ...which leads me to wonder about the use of segments in absolute assemblers, but I'll post that as a new question.